# Update iam_database_authentication_enabled terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have a deployment with an rds database. Initially we set the `iam_database_authentication_enabled` to `false` then run a script setting the database up along with giving the database user the rds_iam role. After that we run apply once more but with `iam_database_authentication_enabled` set to `true`. This is achieved by having two `.tfvars` files. Problem is, the `iam_database_authentication_enabled` is never updated in AWS. I can see when running terraform plan that the field will be updated but in fact it never is. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It will likely be applied in the next rds maintenance window. But if you want to apply immediately, you can use Terraform argument:

```
apply_immediately = true
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't set the `apply_immediately` attribute to `true` in your `aws_db_instance` Terraform code. If you didn't [set that](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance), then the setting will be changed in AWS, but not applied to the running database instance until the next restart.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around it using aws cli:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance \
  --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
  --apply-immediately \
  --enable-iam-database-authentication
```